# POSTing data to netty with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, http, netty

I'm trying to use Apache HttpClient (the fluent API) to POST data to a netty server.

I've tried a few variations, I'll put two here:

### 1.

Client:

```
Request.Post(uri).bodyString("content value", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN).useExpectContinue().execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Server:

```
final HttpPostRequestDecoder decoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(new DefaultHttpDataFactory(false), req);              
System.out.println(decoder.getBodyHttpDatas().size());
```

Calling getBodyHttpDatas() throws a:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestDecoder$NotEnoughDataDecoderException
```

### 2.

Client:

```
Request.Post(uri).bodyForm(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "content value")).useExpectContinue().execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Server:

```
final HttpPostRequestDecoder decoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(new DefaultHttpDataFactory(false), req);
final InterfaceHttpData data1 = decoder.getBodyHttpData("value");

while (decoder.hasNext()) {
    final InterfaceHttpData data = decoder.next();
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            Attribute attribute = (Attribute) data;
            System.out.println(attribute.getValue());
        } finally {
            data.release();
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't print any output - decoder.hasNext() is false.

Comment: it's difficult to deal with 2 issues at the same time, I would try to separate the two problems : use curl to send POST data to you server, make it work and then make your client work.

Comment: Have you tried with these examples http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html? What happen when you do that?

Comment: curl -X POST -d @value.txt [url] gives me the NotEnoughDataDecoderException too. I haven't tried the non-fluent HttpClient API, but I don't believe that's the issue particularly as curl fails similarly.

Comment: Oh, and curl --form "value=@value.txt" [url] also fails with the NotEnoughDataDecoderException.

Comment: Could you trace in your server part what is in you request (`req`) body before trying to decode it ?

Comment: As you can see in the API the exception is thrown due to missing chunks: [API](http://netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/multipart/HttpPostRequestDecoder.html#getBodyHttpDatas%28%29). - Do you mind calling `offer(...)` first or add a pause of 500ms (for test purposes only)?

Comment: Can't see anything unexpected in the request. There's no body I can see on the request, there is a decoderResult which has a success value.

Comment: Pausing doesn't seem to help. I haven't been able to figure out how to get an HttpContent to pass to offer().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the problem you either need to `offer()` all chunks (`HttpContent`) of a message to `HttpPostRequestDecoder` before calling `getBodyHttpDatas()`, or alternatively you can just add the `HttpObjectAggregator` handler right before your handler to the channel's pipeline. If you do so, `HttpObjectAggregator` will collect all chunks for you and produce a single `FullHttpRequest` in place of multiple chunks. Passing `FullHttpRequest` instead of an ordinary `HttpRequest` to `HttpPostRequestDecoder`'s constructor eliminates need to `offer()` chunks.

So you just need to `pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576))` before adding your handler. For example:

```
public class YourServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
        pipeline.addLast(new YourServerHandler());
    }
}
```

`1048576` here is the maximum length of the aggregated content. You are free to pass another value.

Comment: Thanks, there were other issues with my handler, but I managed to modify the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651447/netty-io-client-not-sending-request-body to my needs. This then solved the next problem.